# How to find time complexity of code segments with multiple loops and recursion

Tags: time-complexity

I have attached two code segments for which I want to find the time complexity.

For the first one, I tried using various values of n and figured that it should be something around O(n). However, since there are two loops that refer to different variables, I am a bit confused about how I should go about analyzing the code to find the complexity. [Code Segment 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9hFI.png)

1: i = j = k = 0

2: while k 6 n do

3: i = i + 1

4: j = j + i

5: k = k + j

6: for h = 1 to j do

7: F(i, j, k, h)

8: end for

9: end while

The second one is about recursion. Since I have not had experience of analyzing code with recursion before, I don't really know how to start with this one. Any hint would be appreciated.[Code Segment 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg3Tz.png) Thanks.

1: function F(begin)

2: if begin > n then

3: return

4: end if

5: for k = begin to n − 1 do

6: F(k + 1)

7: end for

8: end function

Comment: Add code instead of image.